# Create a page to show what a specific user has created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, user-controls

I have created an "Article" scaffold and I have set User's authentication with devise. 
I want to create a page that shows all articles cerated by a specific user!

In my articles index is listed all articles and the name of the user that created it, I want others to be able to click on the name of this user and access this page that show the other articles created by this user!

Thanks very much, I started with rails recently and I tried so many ways to do it but I couldn't figure this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you want is all articles that belong to the user.

In your User model add;

```
has_many :articles
```

and in the Article model add;

```
belongs_to :user
```

create a page that returns all articles owned by the user like this

```
@user_articles = User.find(user_id).articles
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a page that shows all articles created by a specific
>   user!

--

**nested resources**

To do that, you'd typically be best using a [`nested resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) (as to identify the parent object), however as you're using `devise`, we have the [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) helper available to use (meaning we can just use the controllers naturally)

If you were to use the `nested resources` approach, you could do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :articles #-> domain.com/users/:user_id/articles/
end
```

This would allow you to call the `articles#index` method in the `articles` controller:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def index
   user = User.find params[:user_id]
   @articles = user.articles
end
```

This is, of course, considering the associations that `acacia` proposed:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
end

#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

--

**current_user**

`current_user` is a helper created by Devise

This means **you don't need to use a nested resource** as you already have the `user` object on hand. I would do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles #-> domain.com/articles

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
Class Articles < ApplicationController
   def index
       @articles = current_user.articles
   end
end
```